# Send data from a WPF Window to a C# class file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to make a simple GUI for a console application I wrote for importing images into a database. I have a xml file that contains the different studies that the images belong to. I am populating a ListBox with the name of these studies. I have a class file named DirectoryNavigator.cs, depending on the name picked from the ListBox, this class runs processes on files within that directory. I would like to know how I can pass the Selected Value from the ListBox to the DirectoryNavigator.cs class file.

here is my WPF window .xaml

```
<Window x:Class="APPIL_Importer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:APPIL_Importer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Gold"
        Title="APPIL Importer" Height="385" Width="600">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource gridBackground}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="StudiesDataSource" Source="/Data/StudyData.xml" XPath="Studies" />
            <DataTemplate x:Key="studyName">
                <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource homeTitle}">DICOM IMPORTER</Label>

        <Image x:Name="appil_logo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Source="/Images/appil_logo.png"/>

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource studyListHeader}" Width="Auto">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource studyListText}">Active Studies</Label>
        </Border>
        <ListBox Name="activeStudiesListBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StudiesDataSource}, XPath=Study}"
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource studyName}">

        </ListBox>



        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Click="Go_To_Study_Importer">Select</Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

here is the xaml.cs file behind the window. I am already capturing the selected value and passing it to another Window, but I don;t know how to do that to just a plain class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace APPIL_Importer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Go_To_Study_Importer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StudyImporter studyImporter = new StudyImporter(this.activeStudiesListBox.SelectedItem);
            studyImporter.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hm... maybe I think you should learn about MVVM.

Comment: First, you have to MainViewModel that binding MainWindow. And then declare DirectoryNavigator class within MainViewModel and you can access from ListBox of the Window to the ViewModel(class file).
If you need a sample code, I could give a sample code.

Comment: sample code would would very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create MainViewModel class that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged as below.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have to bind this ViewModel to the DataContext of the View.
Add to your code-behind file of the MainWindow.xaml as below.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Now it is bound ViewModel(cs) with View(XAML). Therefore you can bring content of the Control to the cs file.

I would show example.

First Add a Model for each item of the ListBox.
I created as below because I don't know your project structure.

```
public class ResearchItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the add to the ViewModel as below. This is instance for binding with the content of the ListBox.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ResearchItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ResearchItem>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And then bind it to the ListBox in the XAML file as below.

```
    <ListBox Width="200" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    </ListBox>
```

Here Items is collection. And ListBox is control to display collection.
Therefore now ListBox will display the Items of the MainViewModel.

But yet, WPF doesn't know how to display the element of the Items because item type is a user-defined type (ResearchItem). Therefore you have to define how to display it as below.

```
<ListBox Width="200" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Name is property ResearchItem.

Now I will fill data into the Items collection as below.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ResearchItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ResearchItem>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items.Add(new ResearchItem() { Name = "The first research" });
        this.Items.Add(new ResearchItem() { Name = "The second research" });
        this.Items.Add(new ResearchItem() { Name = "The third research" });
    }
}
```

When you execute this, you would see what filled data in the ListBox.

Now everything is ready.
I can tell what you want.

To bring selected data of the ListBox, I will added one property as below.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ResearchItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ResearchItem>();

    private ResearchItem selectedItem;
    public ResearchItem SelectedItem
    {
        get => this.selectedItem;
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedItem == value) return;
            this.selectedItem = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items.Add(new ResearchItem() { Name = "The first research" });
        this.Items.Add(new ResearchItem() { Name = "The second research" });
        this.Items.Add(new ResearchItem() { Name = "The third research" });
    }
}
```

Now you have to bind added SelectedItem property to the property(SelectedItem) of the ListBox.

The code is as shown below.

```
<ListBox Width="200" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Everything is over. now you could bring the selected element of the ListBox to the cs file.

The reason we have to do this is to separate design and logic.
I think you should learn the MVVM pattern because it is essential in the WPF.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: this is very helpful, it is a little overwhelming, but helpful. I am going to take a few tutorials on MVVM and re-write my application. Thank you for all this help.