# WPF Cross User Control Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have **two user controls**, one with **input fields** (**Control A**) and another one with **Data Grid** (**Control B**).
How can i **display grid view selected item in textbox** in **WPF**? Is it possible to do it only using WPF or must do inside the program code or both?

Control A with

```
<UserControl x:Class="PayrollSystem.Controls.EmployeeDetailControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<TextBlock Text="First Name : " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

Control B with

```
<UserControl x:Class="PayrollSystem.Controls.EmployeeRecordControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: If you combine two control to one control then work is a little easier. If you have to split control then you should follow the MVVM pattern. This article may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635374/send-data-from-a-wpf-window-to-a-c-sharp-class-file/59653054#59653054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmployeeRecordControl seems redundant. Instead of that, just use a DataGrid directly, and bind its `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` to two properties of a view model class like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    private Employee selectedEmployee;

    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get => selectedEmployee;
        set
        {
            selectedEmployee = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedEmployee)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then create and bind to the view model like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
              CanUserAddRows="False"/>

    <local:EmployeeDetailControl Grid.Column="1"
                                 DataContext="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"/>
</Grid>
```